# Different implementations for a member function C++

Tags: c++, game-engine

I have a strange question. I have started implementing simple game engine in c++/ SFML.
I implemented a message and message queue system so that modules to be decoupled and avoid any confusing dependencies. Also I implemented a class Entity, which represents an object in the game ( contains its position, sprite,...etc ).

each entity has a function called " on_message ", which is invoked by the message queue when a specified entity should receive a message. ( Ex: if entity P1 is the destination of a message coming from P2, msg_queue will invoke p1.on_message passing the msg_type "say damage" to it to do something.

My question, all entities ( objects from class entity ) have now the same implementation of the function on_message. However, this function should differ from an entity to another ( so the player behave different from enemy when "say" space is pressed )

One idea I got is to use inheritance but I think it is not the right as if the game have 100 entity should I make 100 class !?

Is there any efficient ideas that can solve this problem ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: "should I make 100 class !?" what's so strange about it? It's not like the compiler gets tired... Classes are there to model different kinds of "stuff", so if you have 100 entity types it's not absurd to model them as classes.

Comment: I think there is another way of doing so , should the number of classes grow like this with growth of game components ?

Comment: player is quite obviously different from other entities, but how will other 99 differ? It's possible that you can model those differences with data, not functionality.

Comment: what do mean by data no functionality ?

Comment: I was thinking of it as many of engines do, ex: game maker studio, every object can have different events away from others, that's why I am thinking like this

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim: in that case you can provide a `std::function` data member for the callback inside some generic-level `Entity`, to be invoked by the default `on_message` implementation.

Comment: Can u explain more please?

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim: added as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> One idea I got is to use inheritance but I think it is not the right as if the game have 100 entity should I make 100 class !?

This is actually entirely possible, and it may even the "right thing" for entities that are well-defined enough to have their own class. If, besides the behavior on message receive, you start to need data members or other custom functions packaging everything together in a class is a good idea.

On the other hand, if you have a lot of very similar entities with just some difference in behavior when receiving some message, you may have a common superclass which provides a customization point using e.g. an assignable `std::function`. Something like this:

```
struct Entity {
    ...
    virtual ret on_message(msg_type msg) = 0;
};

...

struct LightweightCustomEntity : public Entity {
    std::function<ret(msg_type)> custom_on_message;

    virtual ret on_message(msg_type msg) override {
        if(!custom_on_message) return ret();
        return custom_on_message(msg);
    }
};

// ...

// in reality this would be a smart pointer or whatever
Entity *e = new LightweightCustomEntity;
e->custom_on_message = [](msg_type msg) {
    if(msg.type == SAY_DAMAGE) {
        return ret(42);
    }
    return ret();
};
```

This allows some more runtime flexibility, but notice that you don't really gain much in compactness - especially since C++11 where we can inherit constructors, defining a new class inheriting from `Entity` and overriding `on_message` takes more or less the same code.

Comment: Sorry , but I got only the inheritance and override, can u explain in details what are you doing in this code?

Comment: What's unclear? The lambda function? `std::function`? Have a look at http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html